# Extended with advice: Moving block wont work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Note: this is an extension of a question I just asked, i have made the edits & taken the advice but still no luck**

I am trying to make a webpage where when you click a link, the link moves diagonally every 100 milliseconds.

So I have my Javascript, but right now when I click the link nothing happens. I have run my code through JSLint (therefore changed comaprisions to === not ==, thats weird in JS?). I get this error from JSLink though:

> Error: Implied global: self 15,38, document 31

What do you think I am doing wrong?

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type = "text/javascript">
<!--
    var block         = null;
    var clockStep     = null;
    var index         = 0;
    var maxIndex      = 6;
    var x             = 0;
    var y             = 0;
    var timerInterval = 100;  // milliseconds
    var xPos          = null;
    var yPos          = null;

    function moveBlock()
    {
        if ( index < 0 || index >= maxIndex || block === null || clockStep === null ) 
        { 
            self.clearInterval( clockStep );
            return;
        }

        block.style.left = xPos[index] + "px";
        block.style.top  = yPos[index] + "px";
        index++;
    }

    function onBlockClick( blockID )
    {
        if ( clockStep !== null )
        {
            return;
        }

        block = document.getElementById( blockID );
        index = 0;
        x     = number(block.style.left);  // parseInt( block.style.left, 10 );
        y     = number(block.style.top);  // parseInt( block.style.top, 10 );
        xPos  = new Array( x+10, x+20, x+30, x+40, x+50, x+60 );
        yPos  = new Array( y-10, y-20, y-30, y-40, y-50, y-60 );

        clockStep = self.SetInterval( moveBlock(), timerInterval );
    }
-->
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
    <!--
    @import url("styles.css");

    #blockMenu { z-index: 0; width: 650px; height: 600px; background-color: blue; padding: 0; }

    #block1 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 10px;  left: 10px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block2 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 50px; left: 220px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block3 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 50px; left: 440px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }
    #block4 { z-index: 30; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 600px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; 
              margin: 0; padding: 0; /* background-image: url("images/block1.png"); */ }

    #block1 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block2 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block3 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    #block4 a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

    #block1 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block2 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block3 a:hover { background-color: green; }
    #block4 a:hover { background-color: green; }

    #block1 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block2 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block3 a:active { background-color: yellow; }
    #block4 a:active { background-color: yellow; }

    -->
</style>
```

Comment: Are you able to jQuery or any 3rd party libs?, also if you use jsfiddle.net it would be nice :-)

Answer (score 2):

for starters, self.setInterval and self.clearInterval are not defined anywhere

Comment: do you mean I should remove the self. part? Because I have found numerous tutorials with the function & this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: @Mack: I'd change 'self' to 'window'...but that may not be the issue.  You need to add quotes around the moveBlock() function on this line: clockStep = self.SetInterval( 'moveBlock()', timerInterval );